# How to create encrypted hash passwords for drupal 7

Tags: drupal, cryptography, passwords, md5, cryptographic-hash-function

After searching over internet I came to know that With drupal 7, password are no more encrypted through md5.

What are possible ways to get passwords encrypted in Drupal 7??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With drupal 7, password are no more encrypted through md5.
There are several way to get/set a password in drupal7.
Using drush (for your information, not used in your case):

```
drush upwd admin --password="newpassword"
```

Without drush, if you have a cli access to the server : (for your information, not used in your case)

```
cd <drupal root directory>

php scripts/password-hash.sh 'myPassword'
```

Now copy the resultant hash and paste it into the query:

```
update users set name='admin', pass='pasted_big_hash_from_above' where uid=1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Malik.

After search I found different solutions. Following solution also works

If you are working on a remote environment on which you cannot connect, you can put this specified code in a file such as password.php such as this one:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
  require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
  require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/password.inc';
  print _password_crypt('sha512', $_GET['p'], _password_generate_salt(DRUPAL_HASH_COUNT));
  exit();
}
print "No password to hash.";
```

And then hit your site using: [http://domain.tld/password.php?p='MyPassword'](http://domain.tld/password.php?p=%27MyPassword%27). The hash will appear on your browser's tab.
Don't forget to remove it once you done it.
So, if you want to use some password function generation, have a look on _password_crypt() and _password_generate_salt()

Answer (score 3):

The [`user_hash_password()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!password.inc/function/user_hash_password/7) function can be used to hash password, if you want to use it outside from outside Drupal, you need to bootstrap Drupal configuration.

```
chdir("/path/to/drupal");
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_CONFIGURATION);
user_hash_password($password);
```